# Extract MSISDN headers on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, msisdn

I'm curious about is there any way to detect phone number when accessing my website via 3G.

I did some research on the Internet and found these headers that can help me extract the phone number. But I can not get anything.

```
X-MSISDN
X_MSISDN
HTTP_X_MSISDN
X-UP-CALLING-LINE-ID
X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID
HTTP_X_UP_CALLING_LINE_ID
X_WAP_NETWORK_CLIENT_MSISDN
```

May I extract phone number from the one who accessing my website via 3G?

Answer (score 1):

Some operators are sending x headers on server requests ,based on my recent researches ,I found out that many operators are hiding or encrypting or renaming the x headers and it's hard to retrieve the user's MSISDN , I've tried many ways and If you wanna test your operator, you can use this website [Test Operator's MSISDN availablity](http://www.mulliner.org/pc.cgi)(remember to open the link with your mobile device)
I hope it will help you.